# "Ph" for the /f/ sound; Is Old English responsible for this swap?

Tags: pronunciation, orthography, old-english

Is Old English responsible for creating the /f/ sound from *ph*, as in *Philip*, *Pharoah*, *Physics*, *Sophia*, etc?  Many European countries keep the *f* for all of their /f/-sounding letters, as in *Sofia* and *Stefan*, for example.

Comment: Although you write "keep the *f*", it is actually the case that countries such as Spain  had a spelling reform to change these words to use *f* instead of the *ph* they were using up until this point.

Answer (score 17):

Old English is definitely not responsible for this.

All of the words that you mentioned are Greek in origin, and they all contained the Greek letter φ (phi). In Classical Greek this was pronounced as an aspirated [pʰ], which the Latins wrote as *ph* when they borrowed the words from Greek. Later this sound changed into an [f] in both Greek and Latin, and was passed as such into French, and then into English.

Once the idea that *ph* was pronounced [f] was established, it spread to a few other areas, as well. Borrowings from Hebrew and other Semitic languages sometimes use *ph*, especially since the Hebrew letter פ can be [p] or [f] depending on context. Vietnamese regularly uses *ph* for [f], in this case because the modern Vietnamese orthography was designed by the French.

Comment: +1. But why did the French use "ph" for /f/, if the French language was already using "f" for this phoneme?

Comment: @WS2 What about "philosophie", "photographe", "phénomène" etc.?

Comment: @RobertFurber Quite right - my apologies.

Comment: @RobertFurber you forgot "phonème" 

Answer (score 8):

There were two p, t, and k sounds in ancient Greek. The softer (aspirated) sounds were transliterated in Latin as ph, th, and ch. Then, in Greek, all three sounds weakened; respectively they sounded like f, th (as in think), and the soft throaty sound in German *ich* or the *x* in Spanish *Mexico*. Neither Greek nor Latin changed the way the sounds were written. More than 1000 years later, English was born and then written down by people trained in Latin; they kept the Latin conventions for transliterating Greek words.  You can read a more in-depth explanation about the history of these spellings at tellingvoice.com.

Comment: Could you provide the IPA symbols for the sounds?

Comment: If it was like Hindi, the sounds were [p] for π and [pʰ] for φ. This is what the references [(such as Wikipedia)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ancient_Greek_phonology#Plosives) I've seen say; I'm not sure how scholars know this, since the earlier pronunciations died out centuries ago.

Answer (score 4):

The Romans.  They translated Greek phi (φ) as "ph" and pronounced it closer to "p" than "f".  Native Latin words were spelled with the "f".  Ironically, a lot of Latin p-words became f-words (e.g., *pedis* became "foot").

Comment: Ok, yes, Romans...Greeks phi..this does make sense....many thanks.

Comment: More accurately, the Greek letter φ was pronounced in Classical times as an aspirated /pͪ/ (a bit like /ph/ in "uphill"), and when the Romans borrowed Greek words with that letter they transcribed it as 'ph'. Subsequently the sound changed in Greek to /f/, and Latin (and other languages which had further borrowed the words from Latin) changed them accordingly. "ph" for /f/ is not just in English - it is found at least in French and German as well, though Spanish (for example) has preferred to respell the words with "f". (It's also independently in Welsh and Irish)

Comment: Latin *pedis* did not become English *foot*. Rather, both *pedis* and *foot* are descendants of a common PIE root. The change from *p to *f in the Germanic languages is due to Grimm's Law, which is very different from what happened in Greek/Latin.