# Is “haphazard” a unique word?

Tags: pronunciation

Is ***haphazard*** the only word where *ph* is not pronounced like /f/?

Comment: In *Stephen,* it's pronounced *"v"*.

Comment: Related: [Why is the “ph” pronounced like a “v” in “Stephen”? Is this the only word like that?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/why-is-the-ph-pronounced-like-a-v-in-stephen-is-this-the-only-word-like-t). More distantly related: ["Ph" for the /f/ sound; Is Old England responsible for this swap?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18586/ph-for-the-f-sound-is-old-england-responsible-for-this-swap)

Comment: This is totally phat.

Comment: Yo, homies: hiphop.

Comment: There are lots of compound words (and former compound words) where *ph* or *th* got pushed together without forming the characteristic sound; *haphazard* (a hazard that happens) is one such word.  A word that might *not* be in that category is "upholstery", if only because no one seems to know where the word came from at all.

Comment: I pronounce it like "Haff-hazard"...

Comment: Probably because the 'p' is part of the first syllable and 'h' part of the second syllable??

Comment: @Izkata- Are you joking?

Comment: Why don't you ask a shepherd?

Comment: The comments show that the premise of the question cannot be upheld.

Comment: @Malvolio No, we know where *upholstery* comes from. It comes from *upholster*, which comes from OE *uppheald* (cognate to ONor. *upphald*, MLG *upholt*, MDutch *ophout*, MSw *uppe-, oppehald*) and which in turn comes from  *up-* + *heald* meaning a hold.  We really do know about *upholstery*.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it asks for what seems a trivial list. 'Hophead' is a compound formed from ...p and h... .

Answer (score 37):

No. Trying to find other examples is an uphill battle, though.

In greater detail: Words that came from Greek and have a 'ph' in a single morpheme tend to use the /f/ pronunciation (except some cases like "[Stephen](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/why-is-the-ph-pronounced-like-a-v-in-stephen-is-this-the-only-word-like-t)" where it's /v/ — voiced instead of unvoiced). However, words that were formed by combining separate morphemes (such as [uphill](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=uphill&searchmode=none), [loophole](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=loophole&searchmode=none), [haphazard](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=haphazard), etc) have a 'ph' that belongs to two morphemes and does not represent an /f/ sound.

Comment: You had to go out to the aphelion for such an upheaval.

Comment: *[Aphelion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/aphelion#Pronunciation)* has one pronunciation that upholds the point, another that doesn't.

Comment: @jwpat7 - Stop now, before you hurt his aphelions.

Comment: @jwpat7 I've only ever heard it pronounced as Ap-helion.  Is this a regional variation?

Comment: @jwpat7 Hm, “uphold” … is that pronounced /ˌə'fōld/? Or is it another loofole?

Comment: @jwpat same with *napththa*: it can be naftha or naptha.

Comment: @DanNeely: My dead-tree (and rather old) *American Heritage Dictionary* only lists the "afelion" pronunciation.

Comment: OED also has only /əˈfiːlɪən/ ... I guess we can deduce that Dan Neely is not an astronomer, or he would know how to pronounce "aphelion".

Comment: @GEdgar, I'd expect astronomers, being also familiar with terms like *[parhelion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/parhelion)* and *[perihelion](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/perihelion)*, to say /æpˈhiːlɪən/ (*ie*, p pronounced) rather than /əˈfiːlɪən/.  Note, from [etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?search=helion): aphelion, "point farthest from the sun" ... 1670s, a Grecianized form of Mod.L. *aphelium*, altered by Johannes Kepler based on Gk. *apo heliou* ... from *apo* "away from" ... + *heliou*, gen. of *helios* "sun" ...

Comment: The OED (1973) explains the pronunciation in its etymology - that it's derived from aph + helios (αϕ + ηλιος), and the two Hs kind of merged.  So it looks like the "F" pronunciation would actually be more correct.  This surprises me - I've always given it the "P-H" pronunciation.  I shall henceforth change.

Comment: Here are some other fine candidates: *apehood, bishophood, gossiphood, hophead, kniphofia, loop-hole, paphood, peep-hole, popehood, scamphood, snaphance, straphanger, top-heavy, Uphaliday, upholsterer, wasphood, whip-hand*.

Answer (score 0):

'haphazard' is a word which has 'ph' and is not pronounced as 'f'(a few people may suggest 'amphitheater' as another word but I can't say for sure). However, there are several compound words where 'ph' doesn't sound like 'f' when pronounced. A few of such compound words are:

flophouse,
loophole,
peephole,
uphill,
uphold,
upholster.

Comment: Note that haphazard was also originally a compound (NOAD, [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/haphazard)). My guess is that this is the reason for all cases. It is the same way with *porthole*.

Comment: Also, amphitheater, coming as it does from Greek, should have the 'f' sound.

Comment: I agree with you completely on both the comments. About amphitheater, that's what I believed so I specifically mentioned it, but some people do contradict it.

Comment: Your answer contradicts itself. "peephole" has a "ph" as much as "haphazard" does.

Comment: "Unique" means "the only one"

Comment: @MarkBeadles - All words are unique!  That's the beauty!  (Seriously, though: grrrr.)

Comment: @Mr. Shiny, Mark: the mentioned words other than 'haphazard' are often hyphenated, I have never encountered a 'hap-hazard'. I agree with zpletan because he was right that haphazard was originally a compound word as per the references he gave. However, it is not considered a compound word in present-day English.

Comment: Why a downvote? Why don't u consider contributing to the answers if you know of something better?

Comment: When is the last time you saw "upholstery" or "upholster" hyphenated? They are as much units as "haphazard" is now.  As for downvotes, I feel that if your answer had recognized that "haphazard" is not unique, if you had researched more about "amphitheater", and if you had not called "upholster" a compound word, your answer would have been better. I didn't feel the need to submit an answer since Mr Shiny and New has a fine one.

Comment: Indeed, "upholster" is not a compound, or even a word with a prefix, but a variant of "bolster"!

Comment: @ColinFine -- [citation needed]

Comment: @Malvolio: I withdraw it. It appears I've been a victim of etymythology. In mitigation, I can only offer that it was a long time ago that I read this. I wonder where it was ...

Comment: @zpletan: What you mean "used to be"? "hap" is still in my vocabulary.