# Why is “phony” spelled with a ph?

Tags: etymology, orthography

Who decided to spell “phony” or “phoney” that way and why? Usually, a “ph” can be traced back to a Greek φ (phi), but not so here. Wiktionary says it may come from “[fawney](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/phony#Etymology)”, with no Greek in sight. Was it to seem more learned? That would make the word itself a bit pretentious or foney, sorry, phoney.

Comment: Similarly, “phoo”
A bit less for “phew” (You can find something Greek there). 
“Phoey” is different, from German pfui with a pf sound.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is the "ph" pronounced like a "v" in "Stephen"? Is this the only word like that?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/9772/why-is-the-ph-pronounced-like-a-v-in-stephen-is-this-the-only-word-like-t) See also [“Ph” for the /f/ sound; Is Old English responsible for this swap?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/18586/ph-for-the-f-sound-is-old-english-responsible-for-this-swap) and perhaps others.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following [site](https://mashedradish.com/2016/03/08/the-etymological-underworld-of-phony/) suggests the origin of the term phoney citing lexicographer Eric Patridge and the OED. As for the spelling, they suggest that the use of ph- vs f- was probably influenced by terms of Greek origin which, like telephone, were first used at that time:

> The origin of phones was via American phoney man, a peddler of imitation jewellery.

Partridge notes that  phoney man is:

> from its original, the English fawney man, itself an adaption of the British fawney cove, one who practises ‘the fawney rig’ or ring-dropping trick, involving a gilt ring passed off as gold and first described by George Parker in A View of Society, 1781.

———

> While many etymologists suspect this origin of phoney is genuine, we still not absolutely certain of its truth. If it is true, the spelling of phoney, using ph– for f-, must be influenced by spelling of the Greek-based phone, I imagine. My speculation fits the historical timeline: phone, short for telephone, is recorded by 1880, while phone, as a speech sound in linguistic circles, is documented a little earlier.
>
> And phony‘s passage from Irish to British and American English also generally matches with the Irish diaspora – though I, as a person of Irish descent who is soon moving to Dublin, must take umbrage at the aspersions phony’s origins casts on the Irish.

(mashed-radish.com)

Comment: as fawney was originally Irish for a ring - OED Etymology: Irish fáin(n)e  - and had no connotations of dishonesty, one has to work quite hard hard to take umbrage.

Comment: @Greybeard - if you go through the article, you’ll find the connection between the ring  and phoney.

Comment: @Greybeard Not if "fawney rig" is a common phrase for its time. Words when used in phrases or which are derived from phrases might sometimes be worth more than the sum of their parts.

Comment: Why worry about the initial PH/F distinction and not the final Y/EY distinction? Neither of them matters in the language but one affects dictionary order. Who looks up either one in a dictionary?

Comment: Sham surgery centers who provide ***faux knee*** replacements are phonies. :)